# How to access /res/raw from JNI / NDK C++ code?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Does anyone know how to access a resource from the res/raw folder within an APK from JNI C++ code, or what path it would be when accessed via shell?

Thank,
Kevin

Comment: If it helps at all you can use something like: Uri uri = Uri.parse( "android.resource://com.whatever.package/"+R.raw.asset_name); to load raw resources in components like VideoView, not sure if that works for native.

Answer (score -2):

If you can pass a InputStream, do `getResources().openRawResource(resourceId)`

Comment: No, that is from within Android Java, not Native C/C++

Comment: Found the answer, the data will simply be in /data/app/packagename/res/raw

Comment: How to use the command getResources().openRawResource in JNI.??

Comment: I don't actually see the data in /data/app/packagename/res/raw.

Comment: @Kevin I used "/data/app/com.test.app/res/raw/sample.wav" but file is not open.